# Certain videos pause on phone when headphones are attached

Tags: headphones

I have an Android 9 smartphone and headphones with separate jacks for audio and for mic. I only use the audio jack on my phone. The trouble is the following: when I play some videos with headphones attached they pause every second or so. When I click play they go on for another second and pause again. As this happens, the headphone icon on the top panel is flickering. This happened in media players, youtube app and youtube in browser meaning its not app specific. Even weirder is that it happens only to some videos. E.g I was watching a comedy show on youtube and it was fine. Right after that I tried playing a music video it did what I described above and repeated for any music videos I tried but not for any clips of that show, no matter the lenght. I have some downloaded music and on headphones I could only play things I listened to without headphones earlier. Anything else pauses.

Now, i've seen suggestions that say screen time settings and night time settings sometimes cause this but I double-checked and have none set. Turning battery saver off did nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Clean the headphone jack. It seems like it does not detect the headphone plug reliable. If that does not help it could also be a defect headphone jack (broken soldering point).